# $\forall \epsilon >0,\exists A \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $E \subset A$ and $\mu(A \setminus E) < \epsilon$

Tags: measure-theory

In a measure space $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ with finite measure, $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{M}$ is an algebra. We want to show that if set $E_i \in \mathcal{M}$ satisfies $\forall \epsilon >0,\exists A \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $E \subset A$ and $\mu(A \setminus E_i) < \epsilon,  \forall i$, then $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i$ also satisfies this property.

My thought was to prove $\mu(\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i \setminus \cap_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i) < \epsilon$, however $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra instead of a $\sigma$-algebra which makes it not that straightforward. Any ideas?

Comment: Does $A$ depend on $E_i$? What is $E$?

Comment: your understanding is correct, nice explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, here's what you can do. Fix $\epsilon >0$. For each $i$ and $E_i$, let $A_i \supset E_i$ satisfy $\mu(A_i \setminus E_i) < \epsilon/2^i$,

First, as you suggest, it follows that $\cap_i A_i \supset \cap_i E_i$ and $\mu(\cap_i A_i \setminus \cap_i E_i) < \epsilon$. This is because if $x \in \cap_i A_i \setminus \cap_i E_i$, then $x$ is a member of every $A_i$ and not a member of some $E_i$; that is, $x \in A_i \setminus E_i$ for some $i$. This implies
$$\mu(\cap_i A_i \setminus \cap_i E_i) \leq \mu\big(\cup_i (A_i \setminus E_i) \big) \leq \sum_i \mu(A_i \setminus E_i) < \epsilon.$$

Second, $\cap_i A_i$ might not be a member of $\mathcal A$, but we can approximate it by a member of $\mathcal A$. For all $n$, $\cap_{i=1}^n A_i \in \mathcal A$ and $\cap_{i=1}^n A_i \supset \cap_i E_i$. Moreover, $\lim_n \mu(\cap_{i=1}^n A_n \setminus \cap_i E_i) = \mu(\cap_i A_i \setminus \cap_i E_i)$, so for large enough $n$
$$\mu(\cap_{i=1}^n A_i \setminus \cap_i E_i) < \epsilon,$$
which is the desired result.